# Understanding whether to use two-way effects

Tags: r, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, plm

Using plmtest, I find that individual effects are significant (p: 7.327e-05); time effects are not significant (p: 0.1263); and two-way effects are significant (p: 0.0001197).

Based on these results, should I include two-way effects in my model? Or just individual effects? When I run the model with individual or time effects only, my explanatory variable is significant (p: 1.957e-05 and p: 0.01211, respectively). When I run it with two-way effects, my explanatory variable is no longer significant (p: 0.715998). How can I interpret this result?

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: Thank you, comment is very much on spot! I decided to answer anyway and give at leat a bit of statistical background as I believe question 2 can contain a statistical question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what's on- and off-topic, and thanks very much for the help @Helix123. I will modify to clarify the statistical question(s) I have.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to know whether both effects are significant when introduced jointly into the model. For that, set the argument `effect = "twoways"` for `plmtest`, see the example from `?plmtest`:

```
plmtest(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, type = "bp",  effect = "twoways")
```

The help for that function mentions the references to literature for the various original tests and their extensions. The test is performed on the residuals of the pooling model which does not have "effects", no matter if you input a pooling, FE or RE model.